# Would it be possible to brew cacao powder using a pour over method à la coffee grounds?

Tags: chocolate, coffee, drinks, cocoa, powder

I see that one similar question has already been asked, but it was rather vague on specifics. Essentially, I wish to place a fine mesh strainer over a cup, pour around 1 tbsp of cacao powder (Navitas Organics brand) into the strainer and pour 8 oz of freshly boiled water over the powder, then allow the resulting mixture to drip through.

Having read previous threads in Seasoned Advice, it seems cacao powder, like cocoa powder, isn't fully soluble, hence my idea of treating it like coffee grounds and extracting its properties whilst doing away with the excess particles.

One thing that gives me pause, however, is the worry that the cacao powder will solidify and possibly gunk up the strainer.

What is this community's thoughts? Constructive feedback is very much welcome.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve compared to just stirring cocoa powder into hot water?

Comment: The issue is how well hot water extracts the flavors as it flows past.  If it needs a longer steeping time, you might try fill-your-own tea bags, a really fine mesh tea ball, or a French press.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to disperse the powder in (probably hot, or cold, then heat it) water first, then filter, so not a pour-over method but perhaps close enough.  That's because coffee ground wet better than most powders, as well as generally being coarser, so don't form clumps. I tend to pre-filter with something coarse before using a fine filter, and for testing I would use disposable/compostable filter papers rather than something you may struggle to get clean.

However I doubt you'll get good flavour extraction from raw cacao any more than you would from processed cocoa.  I'd treat them as basically the same as most of the constituent compounds are the same, and most of what I can find to read is based on (roasted) cocoa.

The relevant flavour compounds aren't necessarily very soluble in water - many are only fat-soluble.  These won't make it through your filter. I have successfully filtered warm cooking oil through coffee filters (to make coloured oil dyed with paprika or turmeric) but then you'd have an oily liquid not a water-based one.

It might be worth a try, and you might get a pleasant drink, but I doubt it will taste much like cacao.  Even if you disperse cocoa powder in milk and let it settle until a sludge forms on the bottom of the cup, the flavour is not just far less but also different than drunk straight after mixing.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I suppose it was too much to hope that it would work. But I did a little more digging, and it seems you actually can dissolve cacao powder with a bit of mixing. I've seen some customer review videos on Amazon for the Navitas Organic brand cacao powder that shows it being done. I originally read a Q&A piece by the company stating that they're powder isn't alkalized, so I assumed it wouldn't work too well.

Comment: @AlexWang you need to be sceptical in reading what some people write. The word "dissolve" is often misused in cooking contexts, when the end result is (mainly) a suspension not a solution. If the particles are fine enough, it might not matter for a recipe

Comment: By that, do you mean the food item would literally either suspend in the water or bind with it?

Comment: @AlexWang fine enough particles will suspend

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.